# Asynchronous WCF Timeout in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, timeoutexception

I've got a WPF application that needs to process a list of items asynchronously. As of right now, I loop through the list of items, and for each one, I await the operation. Everything seems to be fine 90% of the time. The other 10% of the time, I'm getting timeout errors (`has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00`). What's weirding me out is that the operations seem to of completed on the backend. Everything looks fine in the database. No errors on the server side. I'm only getting this timeout error on my WPF client.

I'm awaiting my WCF call on each one, so it isn't timing out on the individual call. Each individual call doesn't take long (maybe a few seconds), however the entire operation could take up to a minute or so.

```
private async void MyClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
     await HandleProcessing(MyListOfIds);
}

private async Task HandleProcessing(List<int> Ids)
{
    foreach (var id in Ids)
    {
         try
         {
              // This function makes 2 wcf calls. both 2 are awaited
              int i = await MyFunctionThatMakesWCFCalls(id);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
              //log error
         }
    }
}

private async Task<int> MyFunctionThatMakesWCFCalls(int id){
         bool success = await _serviceClient.MyCall(id);
         if (success){
               return await _serviceClient.MySecondCall(id);
         }
         return 0;
    }
```

So, I suppose each iteration in the loop could potentially take a few seconds (sometimes up to 10). Like I said, even though I get the exception in my log, the data in the backend seems to all be there. I'm not sure how to get around this false positive error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really enough information here - we can't see if the async chain is correct. It sounds like you block somewhere on the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I just added the function. If you need more code from up the chain, let me know. Do you have any initial thoughts?

Comment: What is MySecondCall and why isn't it async?

Comment: And you still need to start at the GUI (Dispatcher / event) level.

Comment: @HenkHolterman My fault. In the process of dumbing down the names, I forgot to add that. That was just a StackOverflow typo. I'm in the process of adding the full process on here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just added the entire flow.

Comment: While this is the rtight pattern you are vulnerable to holdups from everything else on the main thread. Consider awaiting a Task.Run() in the click handler. And do put a try/catch in every async void.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174297/discussion-between-james-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just moved this to chat fyi.

Comment: @James: What kind of WCF binding do you use? Try to increase the SendTimeout and/or ReceiveTimeout properties on the client side.

Comment: @mm8 I can totally do that, but I'm a little confused on how it's timing out considering one single call doesn't span 30+ seconds. Is that timeout based on a single call, or does it somehow group up the entire loop as a whole?

Comment: One goal of  async/await is avoiding to create threads where they are not needed. But I think maybe you do need one. So wrap the call to HandleProcessing in a Task.Run, see what happens. It won't hurt anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I experimented with this today. It didn't fix my issue unfortunately. It actually caused some weird threading issues. I think I've figured out that I'm running into some concurrency/timeout issues on the WCF service side. I open the proxy when the dashboard gets created, and I don't close it until the app itself closes. I believe this could be the smoking gun.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That being said, my users will be using this proxy many times a minute, so closing and re-opening a proxy multiple times a minute seems absurd.